# Migrate SQL Server 2008 to MySQL 5

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

We have a database running on `SQL Server 2008` that I want to migrate to `MySQL 5`. What are the tools needed to migrate live data from the sever to MySQL without doing any SQL coding.

- Is there a utility that will convert from a running SQL Server 2008 to a runnung MySQL server on a machine?
- How about the stored procedures made with SQL Server 2008, can it be automatically converted?

**EDIT**

When I use the MySQL Migration Toolkit, everything seems ok, except during the "Manual Editing" stage where there's a migration message which says:

```
The datatype date cannot be migrated
```

And during the Schema Creation stage I get this migration error:

```
Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause
```

Comment: please use the Edit function to update your question, rather than creating new ones

Comment: @devio Sorry, it was a internet connection issue that caused the post to be send twice

Comment: For copying tables/data from a running SQL Server to a running MySQL server: use Full Convert Enterprise
http://www.spectralcore.com/fullconvert/

For stored procedures translation: use SqlTran SQL Server to MySQL
http://www.sqltran.com/sql-server-to-mysql/

Comment: @DamirBulic Thanks, but I think I will use Talend tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using ETL tools like SSIS or Talend to achive the data migration smoothly.

Comment: Ok, just downloaded it, will give it a try.